# How to attach an ajax event to a non-ClientBehaviorHolder component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In a form I have a `p:inputText` and a `p:colorPicker`as following :

```
<h:outputText value="#{messages.titre}" />
<p:inputText value="#{beanPlanningRessource.equipe.typeRessource.titre}">
</p:inputText>
<h:outputText value="#{messages.couleur}" />
<p:colorPicker value="#{beanPlanningRessource.equipe.typeRessource.couleur}">
</p:colorPicker>
```

And I have a `p:commandButton` which call a managedBean method as following :

```
<p:commandButton widgetVar="ajouter_equipe" 
                             style="visibility: hidden;" 
                             actionListener="#{beanPlanningRessource.ajouterEquipe()}" process="@this"
                    update=":#{p:component('dataTableEquipe')}, :#{p:component('formEquipe')}, :msgs" >
            </p:commandButton>
```

The problem here is that the value in the `p:inputText` and `p:colorPicker` are always null in the managed bean, so in the `p:inputText` I added this line :

```
<p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
```

and now`beanPlanningRessource.equipe.typeRessource.titre` is updated with the value in the `p:inputText`.

The problem I still have is that the `p:colorPicker` is a non-ClientBehaviorHolder component so I can't attach `p:ajax` to it and neither a `f:ajax', so the value attached to the`p:colorPicker`:`(beanPlanningRessource.equipe.typeRessource.couleur`) is always null.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use client-side javascript (jquery events) with a remoteCommand....

Answer (score -1):

Beside jquery you can also use the valueChangeListener

html:

```
<p:colorPicker valueChangeListener="#{beanPlanningRessource.colorChanged}" value="#{beanPlanningRessource.equipe.typeRessource.couleur}"/>
```

bean:

```
colorChanged(ValueChangeEvent event){
   String newColor = event.getNewValue(); 
   //do whatever you want with the new value
}
```

Comment: This is not an ajax event... Completely different thing